# How do i query an inline excel table with vba?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm clearly lacking some knowledge on excel queries.. I need to print out some custom labels with the ordered articles of each worker.

In my example, i have 2 tables:

```
      [tabWorkers]
      ID        Name
      1         John
      2         Patrick


      [tabOrders]
      ID        Article   Amount
      1         Shoe      2
      1         T-Shirt   5
      2         T-Shirt   3
```

I'm looping through tabWorker and for each working i would like to query my tabOrders table: SELECT * FROM tabOrders WHERE ID=1

Syntax example of what i want:

```
    Dim row As Range 
    For Each row In [tabWorkers].Rows 
      myID = row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("ID").Index).Value

      Write( row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("Name").Index).Value & " has ordered...<p>" )

      For Each (Article, Amount) In "SELECT * FROM tabOrders WHERE ID ='" & myID & "'")
        Write( Amount & " x " & Article & "<br>" )
      Next

    Next
```

Comment: i AM able to apply a filter to my table:

    [tabOrders].ListObject.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=myID

but when looping [tabOrders].Rows, i still get all of my rows..

Comment: Only responding to your comment but take a look at `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` method of the range object.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [this](http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/04/02/using-excel-as-your-database/) solution before on large datasets, it works well as long as the data on the tab is well defined

Basically set a reference to ADO then define a connection to the worksheet, remember the $ at the end of each worksheet name :)

```
Dim cn as ADODB.Connection
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL as String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveWorkbook.Name

cn.Open

strSQL = "Select Distinct [Name] From [tabWorkers$] Order by [Name]"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open cn, strSQL, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

'// then use the recordset
for each .......

rs.Close
```